# Undeclared identifier in solidity remix?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I'm new to Solidity.I've got an error from compiling the above code.

```
browser/EHRs.sol:18:9 :Error:Undeclared identifier.require(msg.sender = dotor);
```

Hopefully someone can give some guidance

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract postRecord {

bytes32 public patientRecords;

address public doctor;

function Person() private{

    doctor = msg.sender;

}

struct patient {

    address client;

    bool consent;

    bytes32 name;

}

function setPatientRecords(bytes32 _patientRecords) public {

    patientRecords = _patientRecords;

}

event Post(bytes32 patientRecords, address doctor);

modifier rightPerson {

    require (msg.sender = doctor);

    _;

}

function getRecords()public payable{

    Post(patientRecords, doctor);

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly use `==` to compare values, and secondly pass exception message as second parameter in `require` (you can pass empty string)

```
modifier rightPerson {

    require (msg.sender == doctor, "");

    _;
}
```

[require()](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

**Have a look at this solution**

```
modifier rightPerson {

require (doctor == msg.sender);

_;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside the require statement, you are performing an `assignment` instead of a `comparision`.

`require (msg.sender = doctor);` This assigns `doctor` to `msg.sender` which is incorrect.

Instead, you should use the equality comparison operator `==` to perform the comparision.

`require (msg.sender == doctor);`

And as an answer above suggested, use a revert string for better user and dev experience.

`require (msg.sender = doctor, "PostRecord: Caller must be a doctor.");`

Also, write the contract name with a capital first letter: `PostRecord` instead of `postRecord`.